TimeSeriesDataSet/TemporalFusionTransformer - found class 'NoneType' error, I think it is in the 'target_scale' array
I have tried with and without a normalizer. I am doing this with intraday financial data on one financial product, so only one group for now. The target data was already "normalized", in that it was a percent difference calculation.
Here are the results of df.describe on that column:
count    1228.000000
mean        0.604246
std         3.276353
min       -30.971363
25%        -0.736436
50%         0.000000
75%         1.986204
max        29.972645

The error is
TypeError: default_collate: batch must contain tensors, numpy arrays, numbers, 
dicts or lists; found <class 'NoneType'>

I believe I have isolated the issue to this part. Notice that 'target_scale' contains a NoneType. I don't know why, though.:
error at index 15 with item ({'x_cat': tensor([], size=(31, 0), dtype=torch.int64), 'x_cont': tensor([[-0.5910,  0.5905,  1.3638, -0.2031, -1.3529, -1.2298,  1.5937,  0.7130],
        [-0.5910,  0.5905, -0.0813, -0.2031,  0.1528, -0.5157, -0.2379,  0.7130],
        [-0.5910, -0.7829,  0.8469, -0.2031, -0.9364, -0.4515,  1.5937,  0.7130],
        [-0.5910, -0.7829, -1.1230, -1.2252, -1.0726, -0.3108,  0.6779,  0.7130],
        [-0.5910,  1.9640,  2.1339, -0.2031,  0.2521, -0.0411, -0.2379,  0.7130],
        [-0.5910,  0.5905,  0.5194, -1.2252, -0.4856, -0.2700,  0.6779, -0.2019],
        [-0.5910, -0.7829, -0.0932,  0.8190, -0.6532,  0.1449,  1.5937, -1.1168],
        [-0.5910,  0.5905, -0.5358,  0.8190,  1.1294,  1.7657, -1.1537, -1.1168],
        [ 0.9971, -0.7829, -1.1839,  0.8190, -1.8309, -1.7915,  0.6779,  0.7130],
        [-0.5910,  0.5905,  1.1230,  0.8190, -0.5184, -0.0897,  0.6779,  0.7130],
        [-0.5910, -0.7829, -0.4488,  0.8190, -1.2740, -0.2509,  2.5095,  0.7130],
        [-0.5910, -0.7829,  0.9648,  0.8190,  0.6742,  0.3755, -0.2379, -0.2019],
        [-0.5910,  1.9640,  0.9177, -1.2252, -0.5933, -0.4151,  0.6779,  0.7130],
        [-0.5910,  1.9640,  2.2890, -1.2252,  0.5137,  0.4689, -2.0695, -1.1168],
        [-0.5910, -0.7829, -0.4389, -0.2031, -0.6539, -0.2847, -0.2379, -0.2019],
        [-0.5910, -0.7829, -0.1684, -0.2031, -0.2387, -0.4747,  0.6779,  0.7130],
        [ 0.9971, -0.7829, -0.4708, -0.2031, -1.1305, -0.6797, -0.2379,  1.6278],
        [ 0.9971,  0.5905,  0.0497, -1.2252,  0.8727,  1.1767, -2.0695, -2.0316],
        [-0.5910, -0.7829, -0.3376, -1.2252,  0.7195,  0.2133, -0.2379, -0.2019],
        [-0.5910, -0.7829, -0.1212,  0.8190,  0.9155,  0.2670, -2.0695, -0.2019],
        [-0.5910, -0.7829, -1.0366,  0.8190, -0.0828, -0.2111, -0.2379, -0.2019],
        [-0.5910, -0.7829,  0.6511, -1.2252, -0.3791, -0.6046, -0.2379,  0.7130],
        [-0.5910,  0.5905,  0.2637, -0.2031, -0.8730, -0.6207,  1.5937,  0.7130],
        [ 0.9971,  0.5905,  0.1662, -0.2031,  0.9237,  0.2446, -1.1537, -0.2019],
        [-0.5910, -0.7829,  0.7073, -1.2252, -0.2222, -0.0717, -1.1537, -1.1168],
        [ 0.9971, -0.7829,  0.6207, -1.2252, -0.3063, -0.0754, -0.2379, -1.1168],
        [ 0.9971, -0.7829,  0.8827, -1.2252, -0.4637, -0.0434, -0.2379, -0.2019],
        [ 0.9971, -0.7829, -0.1292, -0.2031, -0.1843, -0.3882, -0.2379,  0.7130],
        [-0.5910,  3.3375,  2.0795, -0.2031,  0.2933,  0.1570, -1.1537, -0.2019],
        [-0.5910, -0.7829, -0.7127, -0.2031,  0.0430,  0.1210, -0.2379, -1.1168],
        [-0.5910, -0.7829,  0.1977, -0.2031,  0.0366, -0.1124, -1.1537,  0.7130]]), 'encoder_length': 30, 'decoder_length': 1, 'encoder_target': tensor([-0.0112,  0.0000,  0.0759,  2.4029, -0.0148, -2.4159,  0.0578, -2.4440,
         0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  2.2859,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,
        -2.2717,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,
         0.0000, -0.0077, -2.1783, -0.0063,  0.0000,  2.1315]), 'encoder_time_idx_start': tensor(1076), 'groups': tensor([0]), 'target_scale': array([0.60424554, 3.27732913])}, (tensor([-2.1231]), None)): default_collate: batch must contain tensors, numpy arrays, numbers, dicts or lists; found <class 'NoneType'>"

Here is my code. There are no nulls in the dataset:
data = pd.read_csv(f'{path_parent}/data/csv/stats_days_5.csv', parse_dates=['Date'])
data.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
data = data.iloc[:-1]
data['time_index'] = np.arange(len(data))
data['group_id'] = 1

print(data.head())

d_variable = 'spf_daily_prf_adj_sum_next_5_fixed'

ind_variables = [f'close_max_{num}', f'close_min_{num}', f'close_score_ave_{num}'
                 , f'count_ml_rev_{num}', f'mid_momentum_score_ave_{num}', f'late_momentum_score_ave_{num}'
                 ,f'mid_reversal_count_{num}', f'late_reversal_count_{num}']

# Train-test split
split_idx = int(data.shape[0] * 0.8)
training_cutoff = data.loc[split_idx, 'time_index']

max_prediction_length = 1  # how many steps to predict
max_encoder_length = 30   # how timesteps of history to use
training_cutoff = data["spf_daily_prf_adj_sum_next_5_fixed"].shape[0] - max_prediction_length

training = TimeSeriesDataSet (
    data[lambda x: x.time_index <= training_cutoff]
    ,time_idx='time_index'
    ,group_ids = ['group_id'] #don't exist yet
    ,min_encoder_length=max_encoder_length #// 2
    ,max_encoder_length=max_encoder_length
    ,min_prediction_length=1
    ,max_prediction_length=max_prediction_length
    ,target = d_variable
    ,static_categoricals = []
    ,time_varying_unknown_reals = ind_variables
    ,target_normalizer=GroupNormalizer(groups=['group_id'])
)

validation = TimeSeriesDataSet.from_dataset(training, data, predict=True, stop_randomization=True)

print("after transformation")

print(data.isnull().sum())
print(data.dtypes)  # Check data types
print(data.isin([np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf]).any())

print("got the line 61")

def debug_collate_fn(batch):
    for idx, item in enumerate(batch):
        if item is None:
            print(f"Found None at index {idx}")
        else:
            try:
                torch.utils.data.dataloader.default_collate([item])
            except TypeError as e:
                print(f"Error at index {idx} with item {item}: {e}")
    return torch.utils.data.dataloader.default_collate(batch)

def custom_collate(batch):
    batch = [item for item in batch if item is not None and item[1] is not None]
    return default_collate(batch)

train_dataloader = DataLoader(training, batch_size=16, shuffle=True, collate_fn=debug_collate_fn)

val_dataloader = DataLoader(validation, batch_size=32, shuffle=False, collate_fn=debug_collate_fn)

# dataloaders
#train_dataloader = DataLoader(training, batch_size=16, shuffle=True)
#val_dataloader = DataLoader(validation, batch_size=32, shuffle=False)

# model specs
model = TemporalFusionTransformer.from_dataset(
    training,
    learning_rate=0.03,
    hidden_size=16,
    attention_head_size=1,
    dropout=0.1,
    hidden_continuous_size=8,
    output_size=7,
    loss=QuantileLoss()
)

# training
def train_model(model, train_dataloader, val_dataloader, epochs=30):
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
    scheduler = ExponentialLR(optimizer, gamma=0.9)
    history = {'train_loss': [], 'val_loss': []}
    
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        model.train()
        total_train_loss = 0
        for batch in train_dataloader:
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            output = model(batch)
            loss = output['loss']
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            total_train_loss += loss.item()
        train_loss = total_train_loss / len(train_dataloader)
        
        model.eval()
        total_val_loss = 0
        with torch.no_grad():
            for batch in val_dataloader:
                output = model(batch)
                loss = output['loss']
                total_val_loss += loss.item()
        val_loss = total_val_loss / len(val_dataloader)
        
        scheduler.step()
        history['train_loss'].append(train_loss)
        history['val_loss'].append(val_loss)
        print(f"Epoch {epoch}: Train Loss {train_loss:.4f}, Val Loss {val_loss:.4f}")
    
    return model, history

for i, batch in enumerate(train_dataloader):
    print(f"Batch {i}: {batch}")
    if any(item is None for item in batch):
        print("Found None in batch")


The full error is:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/candlestick/src/transfomer.py", line 142, in <module>
    for i, batch in enumerate(train_dataloader):
  File "/home/rgn/anaconda3/envs/rapids-23.08/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 630, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "/home/rgn/anaconda3/envs/rapids-23.08/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 673, in _next_data
    data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "/home/rgn/anaconda3/envs/rapids-23.08/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 55, in fetch
    return self.collate_fn(data)
  File "/mnt/c/candlestick/src/transfomer.py", line 82, in debug_collate_fn
    return torch.utils.data.dataloader.default_collate(batch)
  File "/home/rgn/anaconda3/envs/rapids-23.08/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 317, in default_collate
    return collate(batch, collate_fn_map=default_collate_fn_map)
  File "/home/rgn/anaconda3/envs/rapids-23.08/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 174, in collate
    return [collate(samples, collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map) for samples in transposed]  # Backwards compatibility.
  File "/home/rgn/anaconda3/envs/rapids-23.08/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 174, in <listcomp>
    return [collate(samples, collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map) for samples in transposed]  # Backwards compatibility.
  File "/home/rgn/anaconda3/envs/rapids-23.08/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 174, in collate
    return [collate(samples, collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map) for samples in transposed]  # Backwards compatibility.
  File "/home/rgn/anaconda3/envs/rapids-23.08/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 174, in <listcomp>
    return [collate(samples, collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map) for samples in transposed]  # Backwards compatibility.
  File "/home/rgn/anaconda3/envs/rapids-23.08/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 192, in collate
    raise TypeError(default_collate_err_msg_format.format(elem_type))
TypeError: default_collate: batch must contain tensors, numpy arrays, numbers, dicts or lists; found <class 'NoneType'>


Where exactly? Please post the full error trace (as text), and remove any code that may come after the error - see how to create a [mre].

Thank you - I have updated question to include the trace. I don't think that I have included any excess code.
